# Why is this List sometimes null and sometimes not?

Tags: java, android, list

I have an activity that shows the results of the previous activity to the user. I save these results to a database. In my onCreate method I create a reference to my ViewModel and populate a List.

```
 mAtcViewModel = new AtcViewModel(getApplication());
 atcUserStatsList = mAtcViewModel.getAllUsersList();
```

I then go on call the save to database method after this assignment:

```
 private void saveToDB(String playerName) {
    mUser = playerName;

    getAtcUser getAtcUser = new getAtcUser(playerName, this);
    getAtcUser.delegate = this;
    getAtcUser.execute();
  }
```

When I get the result from `onPostExecute` this method is called:

```
@Override
public void processFinish(AtcUserStats atc_user) {

    callOnChanged(atc_user);

}
```

This then calls a method where I am able to see the users previous stored results and adjust them with their new results but in this block of code a problem only sometimes arises, saying that `atcUserStatsList` is null:

```
 try {
        for (int i = 0; i < atcUserStatsList.size(); i++) {
            if (atcUserStatsList.get(i).getUserName().equals(mUser)) {
                mAtcViewModel.updateAtcPlayerStats(mUser, finalDartsHit, finalGamesWon, finalGamesPlayed, finalSinglesPlayed, finalDoublesPlayed, finalTreblesPlayed, finalDartsThrown,
                        finalSinglesDartsThrown, finalDoublesDartsThrown, finalTreblesDartsThrown, finalSinglesDartsHit, finalDoublesDartsHit, finalTreblesDartsHit, finalSecondPlace, finalThirdPlace);
            }
        }
    } catch (Execption e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("atcUserStatsList", "Unable to save to database");
        getMessage("Unable to save to database");
    }
```

When I debug the list is populated most of the time and then when I run the app without debugging sometimes it is empty/null and the snackbar message appears and nothing is saved whereas other times it wouldn't appear and results are saved? Why would this be?

Is it anything to do with the lifecycle?

EDIT:

For example here is the list populated while debugging now this code will work:

[image]

And tbh for some reason it can be hard to get this list not Null when debugging(?).

Comment: Why are you catching `NullPointerException`?

Comment: Aside from the fact that you definitely don't want to catch an NPE, the reason for your `List` being `null` is unclear with the code as is. Likely it will have something to do with the related `View`'s lifecycle, but that won't help you much.

Comment: May not be related to the question at hand, but the way you're creating the `ViewModel`(assuming it's the Architecture Component one) is wrong. Look into the `ViewModelProviders.of` method.

Comment: @luk2302 I wasn't at the start but I began catching it to prevent it form crashing, I'll remove it and just use the snackbar message.

Comment: @NightMare I actually had it the way you mettion like so `mAtcViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(AtcViewModel.class);` but I changed it for debugging but it didn't improve any.

Comment: NPEs are a bug in your code because you (the developer) failed to check the inputs for `null`s and return early. You have to *prevent* them, not *catch* them.

Comment: @COYG it may not affect your current code but if you add more code or change the existing code, something may break. The recommended way of using the `ViewModel` is obtaining one via `ViewModelProviders.of`. Otherwise you lose out on the main benefit of using a `ViewModel` which is surviving configuration changes.

Comment: @luk2302 thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @NightMare I've reverted to using `ViewModelProviders.of`